# Recursive functions with Scheme and how to step with two counters

Tags: recursion, scheme, racket

I'd like to have a function that does the following recursively

```
;f(n) = n, if n<4
;f(n) = f(n-1) + 2f(n-2) + 3f(n-3) + 4f(n-4)
```

This is what I came up with but it does not cover the multiplication at each recursive call. I was wondering how one would implement that with Scheme

```
(define (function n)
  (= counter 0)
  (if (< n 4)
      n
      (+ n (function (- n 1)))))
```

Answer (score 0):

What you currently have written is:

```
f(n) = n, if n<4
f(n) = n + f(n-1)
```

With an out of place, and completely useless `(= counter 0)` statement which can only return `#t` or `#f` (This will give a runtime error if counter is not defined within the scope).

The below code will do what you are trying to acheive. If you want to convert a recursive mathmatical definition to code, you need to have as many recursive funtion calls in the code as you have in the mathmatical definition (in this case, 4).

```
(define (function n)
  (if (< n 4)
      n
      (+ (* 1 (function (- n 1))) (* 2 (function (- n 2))) (* 3 (function (- n 3))) (* 4 (function (- n 4))))))
```